# Regular expression and array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, expression

I have tried to create a own preview function to show the content of an textarea as I type (I know that this works just fine in jQuery (`.html($(this).val()`), but please read more to understand why I use JavaScript to this). This worked well but when I came to add regular expression and array to format `<b>` to `[b]` I got stuck. My code is as follows:

```
function nl2br() {
    var newrows = /\n/g;
    var bold = /\[b\](.+?)\[\/b]/gi;

    find = new Array(bold, newrows);
    replace = new Array('<b>$1</b>', '<br>');

    var messageValue = document.getElementById('preview').value.replace(find, replace);
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = messageValue;
}
```

If I remove one of the lines in the arrays (for example `newrows`), everything is working like a charm, but not with both and that's the problem here. I'm new to JavaScript and asking you nicely if you can see what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you think `replace` accepts arrays? [It does not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: Oh, okey. What function should I use then? :) I have googled it but can't find any replacement

Comment: You just call `replace` twice, or as often as necessary :)

Comment: Okey. How can do I that? I'm a noob at JavaScript :P

Comment: Well, `replace` returns a string, so you just do `...value.replace(a,b).replace(c,d).repl...`. Or you do it in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`replace` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) does not accept arrays as needle and replacement. What happens in this case is that the arrays are converted to strings. In case the array has only one element, it does not make a difference, because the string representation of `["a"]` is just `"a"`. But if you you have multiple elements, such as `["a", "b"]`, it becomes `"a, b"`.

So the solution is to apply `replace` several times. You can either do this through chaining:

```
str = str.replace(a, b).replace(c, d).repl....
```

or, if you want to have it more maintainable, you can keep the needle and the replacement in an array and loop over it. This could look like

```
var patterns = [
    [/\n/g, '<br>'],
    [/\[b\](.+?)\[\/b]/gi, '<b>$1</b>']
];

for(var i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(patterns[i][0], patterns[i][2]);
}
```

---

For learning JavaScript, I recommend the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).